# How to realise in node.js this python code snippet

Tags: python, node.js, linux

I need to write this in Node.js

```
vCmd = any cmd that needs root privileges
vPwd = "1234" #asked before in a seperate dialog
vProc = subprocess.Popen(["sudo", "-S", "xfce4-terminal", "-e", vCmd], stdin=subprocess.PIPE, stderr=subprocess.PIPE)
vResult = vProc.communicate(vPwd + '\n')[1]
```

(Perhaps possible with nested child_process.spawn)
Important is the use of sudo and the password programmatically

Comment: Unfortunately this isn't Google Translate for code. What efforts have you made to convert this yourself? Any errors with that?

Answer (score 0):

Use the `spawn` function in node's `child_process` module, and write the sudo password to stdin:

```
var spawn = require('child_process').spawn;
var vCmd = '<command to execute>';
var args = [ '-S', 'xfce4-terminal', '-e', vCmd ];
// The sudo password
var pw = '******';
// Spawn the sudo command
var proc = spawn( 'sudo', args );
// Log stdout to console.
proc.stdout.on('data', ( data ) => {
    console.log( data.toString() );
});
// Send password to stdin.
proc.stdin.write( pw+'\n' );
// Close stdin.
proc.stdin.end();
```